# How to remove value of input tag

Tags: javascript

I want to not type anything in the input tag when the space key is pressed.

my code working, just always keep one space.For this reason, it does not display placeholder text.

```
input.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
    if(event.charCode === 32){ 
        input.value ='';
    }
});
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to *clear* the text when the spacebar is pressed or just prevent spaces from being added in? Because if it's the latter, just call `event.preventDefault()` in the event listener when the `charCode` matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()`:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
    if(event.charCode === 32){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        input.value ='';
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: This still allows pasting of strings with spaces. ;-)

Comment: @RobG correct, the keypress event does not trigger on paste